# Azure Pipeline YAML vs Wizard

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines

Why is Microsoft creating a YAML file for code deployment? Should I only use the Wizard for initial build and then export the YAML and use it from there on out?

I think that the YAML would be fine if I could re-import it back into the pipeline to reconstruct the Wizard. I don't know how to add things comfortably to the YAML, so this leads to a lot of typos and then creating a simple pipeline to see the YAML created for a specific task.

When should I use the YAML (and why) and when should I use the Wizard (and why)?

Answer (score 2):

well, basically, if you are doing something adhoc, use the wizard, but for something more static, thats supposed to scale and be manageable use yaml. its like asking: "why do you need scripting languages" or "why do you need infrastructure as code". Sure you can always use GUI. But sometimes gui is far worse